# Query Works in phpmyadmin but not on the page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried all kinds of things and spent hours doing this and would really like it if someone can tell me what I'm doing.

This is my SQL query:
`SELECT * FROM txp_file WHERE filename LIKE '%Fast®%' OR description LIKE '%Fast®%'`

In phpmyadmin, this brings back the results I want. On the page, the query apparently works but gets no result. I have tried to use substring to omit the special trademark symbol, I have tried a million different variations but I get no result. Here is my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM txp_file WHERE filename LIKE '%$querytitle%' OR description LIKE '%$querytitle%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if ($result){
    echo "<a href='#'>$querytitle</a>";
}
else
    echo 'nil';
```

The connection to the database is already there so I don't need to do it again in this case. Can anyone find anything wrong with this code?

P.S. $querytitle is a global variable. I have echoed it and it comes up just the way it should.

Comment: What is the character set of `$querystring`, your table, and your database connection?

Comment: so the output of this code is `nil` or `<a href [...]` ?

Comment: How do I find that? I'm sure the character set of the table is utf8

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set the character set for the connection. Use the command:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

or whatever character set you are using. To find the default character set of the database and the connection you can execute this command:

```
USE yourdb;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%coll%";
```

It will show you a list of collations for the server, the database and the connection.